# equal and reverse functions in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a newbie in Common Lisp, going through a tutorial and can't wrap my head around

```
 (equal '(reverse (a b)) '(b a)))
```

returns nil.

Much appreciate your assitance.

M.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting in lisp prevents evaluation of the s-exp and passes it around as a function.

Therefore, you're comparing the non-evaluated function '(reverse (a b)) to the list '(a b)

If you changed the code to

```
(equal (reverse '(a b)) '(b a))
```

(reverse '(a b)) would yield '(b a), and thus the equal comparison would return true.

Comment: I'd say "quoted list" rather than "unevaluated function". The only difference between `(reverse foo)` and `(a b)` is that `reverse` is the name of a symbol in the COMMON-LISP package, whereas `a` is or isn't) a user-defined function.